# How can I control process qemu-system-i386.exe CPU usage (50%) and Memory (1.2GB)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, qemu

I am using Windows 7 with 8GB RAM, latest Android-Studio 2.2, IDEA IntelliJ 2016.2.5 and in the emulator I'm using Nexus 5 API 24. 
It causes heat and the fan is always on.
I tried to change the settings, but it doesn't help.
Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: It's normal. You are using a virtual machine, it should use your resources in order to run properly . . . My AVD is using 3.4 GB RAM.

Comment: I know what you wrote, wanting to limit its usage or find another emulator prefer it's open-source and/or freeware.

Comment: You can use GenyMotion or BlueStacks. GenyMotion is not free :) but you can find cracked one if you want.

https://www.genymotion.com/

http://www.bluestacks.com/

Comment: Thanks Arsen. I know about _genymotion_ not being free and I don't going to pay for something I am not sure suits me 100%. I will check _BlueStack_ and see. thank you again.

Comment: I don't want to promote cracking programs. But you can try cracked one if that fits your needs you can buy.